# How to override indexing functions [ and [[ in R?

Tags: r, indexing

Here is my try:

```
x = list()
x$data = rnorm(26)
x$name = letters
class(x) <- "myclass"
"[" <- function(i, ...) UseMethod("[")
"[.myclass" <- function(...) {
    res = x$data[...]
    names(res) = x$names[...]
}
x[1:3]
```

and it didn't work:

```
> x = list()
> x$data = rnorm(26)
> x$name = letters
> class(x) <- "myclass"
> "[" <- function(i, ...) UseMethod("[")
> "[.myclass" <- function(...) {
+     res = x$data[...]
+     names(res) = x$names[...]
+ }
> x[1:3]
Error in UseMethod("[") :
  no applicable method for '[' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

It seems "myclass" is ignored.

Comment: Normally [ produces an object of the same class as its argument so I would define [ to produce another `myclass` object rather than an object of a different class.  You could define various `as.*` methods to convert a `myclass` object to a different class if that were needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't pass `x` into the function.  Also, you don't need the make `[` an S3 generic; it's already generic.  Finally, you need to return the data at the end of the function.

```
"[.myclass" <- function(x, ...) {
    res = x$data[...]
    names(res) = x$name[...]
    res
}

x[1:3]
#           a            b            c 
#0.3115254677 0.3143685905 0.3592891382
```